# Obtener cuántas veces puedo escribir una palabra en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo mi código donde capturo el texto, la idea es contar cuántas veces se escribe la palaba **BANANA** en ese texto independientemente, ya sea si lo escribo en orden o en desorden sabiendo que la palabra BANANA tiene 1 B, 3 A y 2 N.

Por ejemplo, si escribo **NAABXXAN** me retornará 1 ya que en la cadena está la palabra **BANANA** una vez y desordenada, y si escribo **NAANAAXNABABYNNBZ** me retornará 2 porque en la cadena está la palabra **BANANA** dos veces y también desordenada.

```
let vocalA=["A"];

function contarArray(str){
    let contarVocal= 0;


    for (let i of str.toUpperCase() ){

        if (vocalA.includes(i)){
            contarVocal++;
        }
    }
    console.log("letras A");
    //console.log("letA" + contarVocal);
    return contarVocal
}
contarArray('BASCO')
```

Comment: Sugiero que redefinas el título de la pregunta, ya que no se refiere a cuántas veces escribir una palabra, sino a _cuántas veces está una palabra en una cadena_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo que haría sería colocar la palabra BANANA en un arreglo: ArrBanana[] que pueda recorrer. Luego, la palabra de entrada también la colocaría en un arreglo ArrEntrada[].

Ahora bien, la lógica que yo haría sería

Recorrer letra por letra el ArrBanana y cada letra obtenida, retirarla del arreglo ArrEntrada. si completas un ciclo del ArrBanana entonces sumas un contador IntAux++ por ejemplo. Si alguna de las letras de ArrBanana no la encuentras, entonces finalizas el ciclo y devuelves el contador.

Ejemplo del código:

```
var BolExit = false;
var StrEntrada1 = "BANANA";
var StrEntrada2 = "BANANABANANA";

var StrTest = "";
var ArrPalabra1 = StrEntrada1.split("");
var IntMax = ArrPalabra1.length;
var ArrPalabra2 = StrEntrada2.split("");
var IntRetorno = 0;

function myFunction() {
    while (!BolExit) {
        ArrPalabra1.forEach(FnFindItem);
        IntRetorno++;
    }

    return IntRetorno - 1;
}

function FnFindItem(pStrItem) {
    StrTest = pStrItem;
    StrRslt = ArrPalabra2.find(FnFind);
    if (StrRslt == undefined) {
        BolExit = true;
    }
    else {
        ArrPalabra2.splice(ArrPalabra2.indexOf(StrRslt), 1);
    }
}

function FnFind(pStrLetter) {
    return pStrLetter == StrTest;
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: gracias,  @Gabo77  tienes algún ejemplo de esto de casualidad el código para tomarlo como guía

Comment: Ahí te pasé un ejemplo, ese código funciona. Saludos!

Comment: gracias, te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 3):

Como me gusta reciclar tomaré la función `numberOfCharacters` de esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/561552/301324)

Luego teniendo el número de letras de cada palabra, solo hay dividir para saber la cantidad de palabras que se pueden formar.

por ejemplo:

BANANA

- B = 1
- A = 3
- N = 2

NAANAAXNABABYNNBZ

- B = 3
- N = 5
- A = 6
- X = 1
- Y = 1
- Z = 1

Luego dividimos letra por letra

- B => 3 / 1 = 3
- A => 6 / 3 = 2
- N => 5 / 2 = 2.5 => nos quedamos con la parte entera = 2
- Z, X e Y => no aplican

Luego nos quedamos con el resultado menor, es decir 2.

Aquí el código

```js
function Comparar(palabra, En){
    let entrada = numberOfCharacters(palabra);
    let salida = numberOfCharacters(En);

    let resp=Number.MAX_VALUE;

    for (let l in entrada) {
        if(!salida[l]){
            return 0; // sin no existe la letra, retornamos 0 inmediatamente
        }
        let cantidad = parseInt( salida[l] / entrada[l]);
              
        if(cantidad<resp){
            resp = cantidad;
        }
    }
    return resp
}

function numberOfCharacters(string) {
    let result=[];

    for(let i=0; i<string.length; i++){
        if (result[string[i]]){
            result[string[i]]++;
        }
        else{
            result[string[i]]=1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log( Comparar("BANANA","NAANAAXNABABYNNBZ")  );
console.log( Comparar("ANA","NAANAAXNABABYNNBZ")  );
console.log( Comparar("BABA","NAANAAXNABABYNNBZ")  );
console.log( Comparar("AXN","NAANAAXNABABYNNBZ")  );
console.log( Comparar("CASA","NAANAAXNABABYNNBZ")  );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Amigo,  me sirvió mucho tu código.