# Como iterar un string y devolver el número de veces que se repite uno u otro caracter, dentro de un objeto { clave: valor, clave: valor ...}

Tags: javascript

he estado tratando de desarrollar este ejercicio pero no encuentro solucion, si alguien fuera tan amable de tratar de explicarlo, muchas gracias de antemano.

//La función recibe un string. Recorre el srting y devuelve el caracter con el número de veces que aparece
//en formato par clave-valor.
//Ej: Recibe ---> "adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda" || Devuelve ---> { a: 5, b: 2, c: 2, d: 4, f: 4, h:1, j: 4, s: 5 }

```
var string = "adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda"

function numberOfCharacters(string) {
var object = {};
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
object = string[i] ?? 0;
//hasta aqui llegue
}
```

Comment: ¿No has intentado nada? Te invito a que mires las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/559266/169744). Yo haría el código para esta tarea muy parecido al de esas.

Comment: Hola amigo espero esto te sea de ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315042/calcular-cuantas-veces-aparece-cada-letra-con-javascript

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Que tengo que hacer para que no me suceda esto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/561846/que-tengo-que-hacer-para-que-no-me-suceda-esto)

Comment: Por lo visto, tienen un docente que poco explica: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/561846/822 aquí otro compañero con el mismo código.

Answer (score 3):

Usando un objeto, yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```js
function numberOfCharacters(string){
    string = string.toLowerCase()
    resultado = {}

    for (char of string)
        resultado[char] = (resultado[char] ?? 0) + 1

    return resultado
}

// Código de prueba 
console.log(numberOfCharacters("Un jugoso zumo de piña y kiwi bien frío es exquisito y no lleva alcohol."))
```

Recorre cada carácter de la cadena con un for sumando 1 para cada uno. El operador [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) evalúa si la propiedad está definida. Si lo está devuelve su valor. Sino devuelve 0 y al sumar 1 se define como 1.

La idea es la misma que la de @Yussef pero adaptando el código de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/559307/169744) que hice.

Comment: menos lineas de codigo, definitivamente javaScript me encanta... lo estoy aprendiendo y la comunidad es muy grande... se agradece tu respuesta @Mateo

Answer (score 1):

Un objeto se puede instanciar de esta manera:

`let objeto = {};  // Es igual a let objeto=new Object()`

Luego un objeto puede tener propiedades, que se asignan con un punto

`objeto.propiedad = "valor propiedad"`

Una propiedad es un atributo de un objeto. Un objeto 'persona' puede tener la propiedad 'cantidad_piernas' y cuyo valor puede ser 2

A ti lo que te piden es devolver un objeto que tiene 'n' propiedades, las cuales son las letras de la palabra de ingreso.

Además hay que considerar que:

- Un string puede recorrerse con un for igual que con un array
- if( objeto["nombre_propiedad"]) retorna true si la propiedad existe o false en caso contrario

```js
function numberOfCharacters(string) {
    let result={}; //Objeto que guardará el resultado

    for(let i=0; i<string.length; i++){
        if (result[string[i]]){ //Existe la propiedad???
            result[string[i]]++; //Si existe, le sumamos 1
        }
        else{ //No existe. La creamos con valor 1
            result[string[i]]=1; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log( numberOfCharacters("adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda") );
```

Comment: Como me dijeron a mí una vez. ¿No piensas dejar que OP se esfuerce o al menos explique qué es lo que se le dificulta? Yo también habría respondido ya. Pero hay que abstenerse de responder hasta que la pregunta mejore.

Comment: @Mateo La verdad es que no iba a responder, pero encontré una pregunta que me pareció entretenida https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/561536/301324 por lo que decidí responder las 2 ocupando este mismo código

Comment: bueno, enrealidad si lo intente y mucho pero como se me dificulto plantearlo publique el ejercicio sin mi codigo ya que como digo no encontraba forma de plantearlo, se agradece la respuesta, a continuacion publico el mismo codigo comentando el flujo de control para entender la logica, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
function numberOfCharacters(string) {
let result={};

for(let i=0; i<string.length; i++){
    if (result[string[i]]){//1- aca valida si existe cada uno de los caracteres (los itera), como no existe pasa al else
        result[string[i]]++;//3- regresa al if, esto da true (ya existe {a: 1}) y en esta linea [string[i]]++ le suma 1
                            //   como un contador de key:value donde key = a y value es 1 + 1. todo esto iteracion por iteracion.
                            //   ¿es correcto lo comentado de como funciona el flujo? si estoy en algo mal por favor corrijanme...
    }
    else{
        result[string[i]]=1;//2- aqui por cada iteracion le asigna a cada caracter el valor de 1, cuando se encuentra con 
                            //   el mismo caracter digamos {a: 1} sale del else ya que ya existe y tiene un valor asignado.
    }
}
return result;//4- al final de iterar toda la cadena retorna el objeto result con las propiedades y los valores establecidos.
}

console.log( numberOfCharacters("adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda") );
```

gracias por la respuesta enrealidad me costo mucho entender este codigo, lo publico comentado... si mi logica o mejor dicho si lo entendi mal por favor corrijanme y muchas gracias @Yussef

Comment: No deberías usar las respuestas para hacer preguntas. Podrías haber usado los comentarios. Bueno, el if se encarga de revisar si ya está la clave en el diccionario. No es la forma más clara de hacerlo pero cumple con el objetivo. El resto está bien.

Comment: ok, gracias por el consejo...

Comment: @Miltonext  Esa es la lógica! - Para revalidar: En (1) lo que hace es validar si existe la ```propiedad``` creada. Luego, si existe le suma 1, si no existe la crea y le asigna un 1

Comment: @Yussef si logre comprender tu codigo, aun que me costo... gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria con un `reduce`:

```js
const charactersCount = (sentence) => {
  const characters = sentence.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '').split('');
  
  return characters.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
    ...acc,
    [cur]: (acc[cur] || 0) +1,
  }), {});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo haces con **Reduce** lo tienes compacto en 1 línea.

```
let string = 'adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda';
var result = [...string].reduce((p, c) => { p[c] = p[c] ? p[c] + 1 : 1; return p }, {});
console.log(result);
/*
Resultado:
a:5
d:4
s:5
j:4
f:4
h:1
c:2
b:2
*/
```

Siendo p: previousValue: y c: currentValue.

Lo he sacado de [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55540351/12467254) de la comunidad inglesa por si quieres revisar otras respuestas.