# Contar número de veces que aparecen los caracteres en una cadena

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy aprendiendo js y tengo una tarea que estoy haciendo que me sale casi bien, la consigna es la siguiente:

La función recibe un string. Recorre el string y devuelve el caracter con el número de veces que aparece

```
//en formato par clave-valor.
//Ej: Recibe ---> "adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda" 
//Devuelve ---> { a: 5, b: 2, c: 2, d: 4, f: 4, h:1, j: 4, s: 5 }
```

y mi código es el siguiente:

```
function numberOfCharacters(string) {
  let objeto = {}
  string = string.split("").sort()
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let contador = 1
    if (string[i] === string[i+1]) {
      contador++
    } 
    let letra = string[i]
    objeto[letra] = contador 
  }
  return objeto 
}
```

Me devuelve lo que me pide la tarea, pero también me devuelve ademas un key-value, como *key* cada letra que se repite 2 o mas veces y de *valor* siempre `1`, además creo que no me devuelve los key value de los caracteres que solo están puestos en el string una vez. Necesito ayuda por favor, no sé qué más hacer para que funcione el código correctamente.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/561552/301324

Comment: El problema está en que el `for` siempre resetea el contador a `1` en cada iteración. Cuando llega a la última letra repetida, no va a entrar al `if`, por lo tanto escribe `objeto[letra] = contador` (o sea `1`). La mejor solución es la que te dieron en la respuesta.

Comment: Aquí otro compa con el mismo problema, el mismo docente quizás y probablemente sean compañeros de aula: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/561541/822

Answer (score 1):

Te estás complicando demasiando.

No necesitas hacer `split`, una cadena de por sí, es un array de caracteres. No necesitas sortear la cadena. No necesitas contadores, no necesitas comparar índices.

Simplemente, crea una entrada en `objeto` con cada letra y aumenta en `1` el contador cuando exista o establécelo a `1` si no existe usando el [operador OR de asignación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment): `++objeto[string[i]] || 1`. No hay más historia.

Veamos:

```js
console.log(numberOfCharacters("adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda"));
function numberOfCharacters(string) {
  let objeto = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      objeto[string[i]] = ++objeto[string[i]] || 1;
  }
  return objeto 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
function numberOfCharacters(palabra) {
  var objeto = {};
  string = palabra.split('').sort();
  for (let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
    letra = string[i].charCodeAt();
    if (objeto[letra] === undefined) {
      objeto[letra] = 1;
    } else {
      objeto[letra]++;
    }
  }
  total = {};
  for (let i in objeto) {
    total[String.fromCharCode(i)] = objeto[i];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(numberOfCharacters('adsjfdsfsfjsdjfhacabcsbajda'));
```